# Immediate text display

Tags: android, xml, webview, background

In my android app I have `textview` to justify text I have used `webview`. And I am setting background `image` in `xml`. But the problem is that when I press `button` in main menu of app to open new activity to display text. Its first show background and after some time text is displayed. I want when I press `button` its show text immediately.

Code-

```
setContentView(R.layout.benefits);
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bText)).addView(view);
view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
view.loadData(getString(R.string.benef), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:background="@drawable/back">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_space_waster"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

      <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/bText"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="8"
       android:gravity="center">            
       </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button 
                android:text="BACK" 
                android:id="@+id/back2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@null"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Someone suggest me to use Asynctask but I dont think its help to show text immediately.

Comment: How much time it takes to display the text?

Comment: You load your WebView intially and make it invisible And you click on button make it visible.

Comment: ok how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Initially make your webview invisible like this `WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and on click of button `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.

Comment: no You dont understand. wait i edit question.

Comment: And please provide your answer not in comment because if it works then i accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use WebView to justify text, webviews are very slow. In your case I would use:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your string in form of HTML"));
```

-just a normal TextView with the text in form of html